# get.php in server logs - security issue?

Tags: magento-1, image, security

I noticed multiple hits per day on `get.php` in the access logs of a Magento 1.14 store, resulting in PHP errors and a HTTP 500 response.

Some of them have bot user agents like `facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)` or  `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)`, some come from Outlook and most do not have a user agent at all, but often from the same few IP addresses at the same time of day.

Is there a logical explanation for that other than somebody is trying to gather information or exploit security holes in `get.php`? We never used the feature to store images in the database, so there is no legit usage for this script.

I reckon, it is safer to delete the file to eliminate a possible attack vector, but first I'd like to understand what could be going on there. Any ideas?